# How do I make "snap to face" to work?

Tags: snapping

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1isb0x4zYw&list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD&index=4) and, while adjusting the icing to the Donut (3:42m), the instructor says I should enable snapping so that the icing would snap to the face of the donut.

I did so as the screenshot below:

[image]

However, when I'm moving a vertex (G), it's totally not snapping, as you can see on this screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've answered your question, check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in your screenshot, you have *Project Individual Elements* on, making it project only the vertex you selected. Also, the distance you're moving your vertex from the doughnut is too far away. I hope this helps.

Comment: Project Individual Elements have been suggested by the tutorial. The way I understand it, it makes the vertexes from "Proportional Editing Objects" to also snap. Your point on the vertex being too far, though, was on point. The controls for snapping are really clumsy, at least in this specific case. It's not easy to understand what is going on. After experimenting a lot, I understood snapping was really working, except if I drag vertexes too far. Thanks a lot for your help.